# Opencv: What is the procedure for finding specific pattern in black background?

Tags: opencv

The following shows the contour of an image having a QR code:

[image]

From this image I have to extract the QR code which is my ROI. To get these contours I used

```
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

I have drawn those three yellow lines manually just to show that I need to identify these patterns.  Once I know the location of these three points, it would become easier for me to locate the QR code.

Another with one color:
[image]

All QR codes have such three boxes. Such as this sample:

[image]

Please help me proceed.

**Note:** There is another problem  with this image , and that is it is radially distorted, which I am ignoring for the time being. At present I just need this ROI having the full QR code.

**Update**

As suggested by [Micka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2393191/micka), I should look for all such contours that have 2 different contours included (hierarchically). The result would be that all trash contours will be removed  and only those three boxes will be left.

So  now my question is how do I get such contours from `contours` that I have got by calling the following function:

```
findContours( canny_output, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Point(0, 0) );
```

Comment: I guess finding QR Codes is easier on color texture images than on contour images. If you have access to the openCV contours (and not just the contour image) you could first select all contours that have 2 different contours included (hierarchically). This should reduce the number of contours and still include the corner cubes of your QR code

Comment: Yes I do have contours. So can you tell me how do I select all such contours that hat have 2 different contours included (hierarchically).?

Comment: openCV gives you the hierarchy, so you can see how many outer-contours a contour has. but I never used that information yet, so no direct help from me, sorry.

Comment: If you have access to the color images, try "Fast QR Code Detection in Arbitrarily Acquired Images." (found by google): https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221337868_Fast_QR_Code_Detection_in_Arbitrarily_Acquired_Images or search on stack overflow, there is another method.

Comment: @Micka I posted some of my progress in [Opencv: Finding specific contours based on some condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27061121/opencv-finding-specific-contours-based-on-some-condition)

Comment: as color image I meant the input image even before canny operation. If I find the time I'll try to have a look at those openCV hierarchy element, but not sure if or when this will be.

Comment: @Micka Thanks for your suggestions. I have those original coloured images. I generated these contour from that image only. I need to ask my boss regarding its confidentiality. Then I will post it you require.

Comment: ok so i would suggest you to try different methods which work on color images directly instead of using canny and contour extraction. Did you have a look at the paper I linked before? "Fast QR Code Detection in Arbitrarily Acquired Images"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter on the number of contours including in a contour of interest, you should use the hierarchy variable. A possible code to do it would be:

```cpp
void updateInclusionScores(std::vector< std::vector<int> > const& hierarchy, 
                           std::vector<int>& scores)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < hierarchy.size(); ++i)
    {
        scores[i] = 0;
        if (hierarchy[i][3] >= 0)
        {
            int current = i;
            while (hierarchy[current][3] >= 0)
            {
                current = hierarchy[current][3];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then, you can filter your contours based on their inclusion count stored in `scores`.

(I've purposefully ignored the issues of allocating `scores`and optimizing the score computation. Also, there should be a nice way of expressing this filtering operation using functional programming, especially when using C++11, but you see the idea.)

As an alternative, I would also suggest computing line directions using Hough transform, then building squares from the lines found by the Hough routine. This method was used a few years ago to detect the squares of the calibration patterns because it is robust to the occlusion of some line intersections (i.e., square corners missing in the image).